# Proof without mean value theorem that continuously partially differentiable implies differentiability

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

For simplicity we consider the case of $2$ factors. Let $E_1,E_2,F$ be Banach spaces and $f:X\to F$, where $X\subseteq E:=E_1\times E_2$ is open. By first partial derivative we mean the derivaitve of $f(\cdot,e_2)$ when we fix $e_2\in E_2$. Second (or other) partial derivatives are defined analogously.

I'm trying to prove the following theorem from H. Cartan's *Differential Calculus*:

[image]

This is the proof provided in the book:

[image]
[image]
[image]

where the mean value theorem used is this:

[image]
[image]

My question: Can we avoid the use of the mean value theorem? I think proving $(3.7.2)$ doesn't need the mean value theorem. Here is my proof:

That $f$ is differentiable at $x_0\in E$ with derivative $\partial f(x_0)$ is equivalent to saying that $$f(x)=f(x_0)+\partial f(x_0)(x-x_0)+r(x)\|x-x_0\|,$$ where $r:X\to F$ is continuous at $x_0$ with $r(x_0)=0$. Therefore, we have (again considering the case $n=2$ for simplicity) $$f(x_1,x_2)-f(a_1,x_2)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(a_1,a_2)(x_1-a_1)=\Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(a_1,x_2)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(a_1,a_2)\Big)(x_1-a_1)+r(x_1,x_2)\|x_1-a_1\|.$$ Since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}$ and $r$ are continuous at $(a_1,a_2)$, we can choose $\delta>0$ such that, for all $\|x_1-a_1\|+\|x_2-a_2\|<\delta$ (using the $\|\!\cdot\!\|_1$ product norm), we have $\big\|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(a_1,x_2)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(a_1,a_2)\big\|\leq\varepsilon/2$ (operator norm) and $\|r(x_1,x_2)\|\leq\varepsilon/2$, so $$\Big\|f(x_1,x_2)-f(a_1,x_2)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(a_1,a_2)(x_1-a_1)\Big\|\leq\varepsilon\|x_1-a_1\|.$$

Is my proof correct? If so, why is the author using the mean value theorem (which does not really simplify the proof in my eyes)?

Answer (score 1):

You error occurs at the point of the proof where you write "we can choose $\epsilon > 0$ such that....".

You are not free to choose $\epsilon$ as you might wish to.

The statement you must prove at this point is:

- For all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\eta > 0$ such that if $\|x_1-a_1\| < \eta$ then
  $$(*) \qquad \|f(x_1,x_2)-f(a_1,x_2)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(a_1,a_2)(x_1-a_1) \| < \epsilon
  \|x_1-a_1\|
  $$

One never starts a "for all $\epsilon > 0$" proof by saying "choose $\epsilon$ so that...". You do not have the freedom to choose $\epsilon$.

The mechanics of proving this statement are that you are *given* a value of $\epsilon>0$. Then you must *find* an appropriate value of $\eta > 0$, and use to prove that if $\|x_1-a_1\| < \eta$ then the inequality $(*)$ is true.

Take a look at what the mean value theorem says (I note that you did not copy the whole theorem in your post; you omitted the conclusion). You'll see how useful it is in carrying out the mechanics of the proof.

Comment: Sorry, I think it was a typo... I'm really sorry. Let me rephrase...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I didn't post the conclusion part of the mean value theorem!

Comment: Dear Lee Mosher, I was wondering if you could take some time to examine my proof? Now that 7 days have passed and my bounty has expired, and there is no answer yet... This question is fairly important to me. I'm studying on my own, so this is the only way to check whether I really understood the theory. Thanks in advance!